# Why md5 hash of a word from a file doesn't match the hash of a string?

Tags: python, file, hash, md5

I'm trying to create a python program that would read words from a dictionary, create a md5 hash and compare it to a given hash.

Everything works fine when I try to compare two hashes of words that haven't been read from a file:

```
if hashlib.md5(b"string").hexdigest() == "b45cffe084dd3d20d928bee85e7b0f21":
    print("Equal!")
```

But when I read the words line by line from a file, the hash of the word is different. The code looks like this:

```
f = open('short.txt', 'r')

stringHash = 'b45cffe084dd3d20d928bee85e7b0f21'

for line in f:

   if stringHash == hashlib.md5(line.encode('utf_8')).hexdigest():
       print("Found it! Password: %s" % line)
```

Thanks for any help and explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

line-by-line file iterator yields the whole line *including line terminators*.

In your code, you're including the line terminator of the line.

`line.encode('utf_8').rstrip()` will yield the correct result.

`rstrip()` will fail if your string ends (purposedly) with spaces. In that case, just do:

```
line.encode('utf_8').rstrip('\r\n')
```

if the file is open in *text* mode on Unix, possible `\r` (carriage return) could remain (not a problem on windows)

(and `rstrip` does not remove the '\r\n' string, but each `\r` or/and `n` contained at the end of the line, it's not like `str.split`)